# DNA/Half-Sibling or First Cousin, Based on Fairly High Shared cMs

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, 23andme

Brand new at this and don't have good grip yet on cMs ranges for relationships, especially when number falls in between stated ranges for relationships.

Both my dad and I have taken DNA tests from 23 and Me. We share a match, and 23 and Me says this person and I likely share a set of grandparents...that we are first cousins (we share 8.92% DNA, and [664 cMs](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/664) across 21 segments). My dad shares [1,260 cMs](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1260) with this match across 35 segments (can't see percentage shared).

My father is the only child his parents share, so match and I can't be (whole) first cousins.

Match is likely my first cousin once removed (father's first cousin) or is it possible that match is my half-aunt/uncle (father's half sibling, unknown to us from other relationship had by my paternal grandfather)?

Answer (score 1):

Try DNAPainter for a set of possible (probable) relationships.

[664cm](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/664) has options for you; while
[1260cm](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1260) has options for your father.

Hopefully you can find a pair of relationships that satisfy both of you.

For example, it shows a 69+% probability of a 1C match for your dad, and a 44+% probability for a 1C1R for you. Not saying that's the truth, but that's a possibility.